# Creating dynamic links on pointerdown event -JointJS

Tags: jointjs

Is it possible to create interactive dynamic links in JointJS starting from a reference point (x,y) instead of drawing it from a port or using a halo.

Regards
Achyut

Answer (score 4):

There are some undocumented methods in JointJS which might help you solve this. More inline.

```js
paper.on('blank:pointerdown', function(evt, x, y) {

    var linkView = this.getDefaultLink()
            .set({
                'source': { x: x, y: y },
                'target': { x: x, y: y }
            })
            .addTo(this.model)
            .findView(this);

    // initiate the linkView arrowhead movement
    linkView.startArrowheadMove('target');

    $(document).on({
        'mousemove.example': onDrag,
        'mouseup.example': onDragEnd
    }, {
        // shared data between listeners
        view: linkView,
        paper: this
    });


    function onDrag(evt) {
        // transform client to paper coordinates
        var p = evt.data.paper.snapToGrid({
            x: evt.clientX,
            y: evt.clientY
        });
        // manually execute the linkView mousemove handler
        evt.data.view.pointermove(evt, p.x, p.y);
    }

    function onDragEnd(evt) {
        // manually execute the linkView mouseup handler
        evt.data.view.pointerup(evt);
        $(document).off('.example');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It's working like a charm. I'm new to Javascript and JointJS. I could understand that on mousemove & mouseup respective functions are called. But, how is .example been used? What is the importance of assigning .example to mouse events?

Comment: It's not important for the demo to work correctly. I used [namespaces](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) only to reference both `mousemove` and `mouseup` listeners in `onDragEnd()`.

Comment: Yeah! I got it. I guess it's just the namespace used to refer the mouse events.